# MySql delete in column after ;

Tags: mysql, database

Hi I haven a column in my SQL that contains urls, howoever I'll have to modify it to only keep the first one

Column name Thumbs 
DATA ex. http://sub.domain.com/t/003/4_b_3.jpg;http://sub.domain.com/t/003/1_b_3.jpg;http://sub.domain.com/t/003/2_b_3.jpg;http://sub.domain.com/t/003/3_b_3.jpg;http://sub.domain.com/t/003/5_b_3.jpg;http://sub.domain.com/t/003/6_b_3.jpg;http://sub.domain.com/t/003/7_b_3.jpg;http://sub.domain.com/t/003/8_b_3.jpg;http://sub.domain.com/t/003/9_b_3.jpg;http://sub.domain.com/t/003/10_b_3.jpg

The result should be like http://sub.domain.com/t/003/4_b_3.jpg and nothing else

Can anyone help me with the syntax?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You could combine 2 string functions: INSTR() and SUBSTR(). More information you can find at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html.

Comment: Is this one long string? Or multiple rows? Or what?

Comment: one long string in one row called thumbs in table [tablename], there all seperated by ; and have shall only keep the first value in the row

Comment: Is it me who is complete stupid? --> you are saying it yourself, but `[table]` and `[url]` are placeholders I used, because I couldn't find the real names in you example code. You have to replace these with the actual table and column name. Please delete your answer, since it's not an answer. The comments section is designed for this.

Comment: Looking at the original post I think the edit should be rolled back at it seem to have changed the sample data and obscured the intent of the question. @Mouser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming ([from your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27760529/mysql-delete-in-column-after#comment43932626_27760529)) that `Thumbs`is a long string (which it seemed to have been in your original question, before the edit which I believe might have been incorrect), this will remove everything after the first occurrence of `;`

```
update tablename
set Thumbs = left(Thumbs , instr(Thumbs , ';')-1)
where instr(Thumbs , ';') > 0;
```

[Sample SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/431037d/4)

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest using `substring_index()`:

```
update tablename
    set Thumbs = substring_index(Thumbs, ';', 1)
    where thumbs like '%;%';
```

This function is designed to extract the first portion of a delimited string.

Answer (score 1):

Use the not operator `<>`

```
DELETE FROM [table] WHERE url <> 'http://sub.domain.com/t/003/4_b_3.jpg'
```

This will delete all rows except the one with `http://sub.domain.com/t/003/4_b_3.jpg`

Or generic:

```
DELETE FROM [table] WHERE [url] NOT IN (SELECT TOP 1 [url] FROM [table])
```

The generic one returns the first row of the table and exempts it from the delete.

To test and not be sorry use (MySQL):

```
START TRANSACTION;
    DELETE FROM [table] WHERE url <> 'http://sub.domain.com/t/003/4_b_3.jpg';
ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
```

The `DELETE` will be performed but rolled back afterwards, when it works, execute without `tran`.

Comment: I think it's clear that hardcoding one particular URL is not what he is looking for. This solution is 100% non-generic. He might as well have just hand-input that row in the first place.

Comment: thanks but gives me an error when i try to use the % for variables
http://%.domain.com/t/%%%/%.jpg

/* SQL Error (1064): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'TRAN
    DELETE FROM table WHERE url <> 'http://%.domain.com/t/%%%/%.jpg'
' at line 1 */

Comment: @Joakim You are using MySQL and the `BEGIN TRAN` works only on MSSQL will update example for MySQL

Comment: @Joakim if you are going to use wildcards `%`, you need to use the operators `NOT LIKE` or `LIKE`. In your case `LIKE` instead of `<>`.

Comment: A bit old thread, how ever I used jpw answer, and it worked as supposed, but thx for your inputs, I can see other have had create use of these :)